# How to run Linux 'at' command to Apache account?

Tags: php, linux, at-job

If you register at a command using the shell script is running well.
However, it does not run when you register at the command using php.

When registering as a shell script,

> 61 2015-09-15 14:53 a root

When using php,

> 62 2015-09-15 14:53 a Apache

Both properties are, however,
It is registered as a user at Apache not be executed.

How to run Linux 'at' command to Apache account?

Answer (score 1):

it's because of your php is running under apache user privilage you have 2 way to fix this:

but before every thing check your script and be sure it's need to be run as root if script dont need that you just need add right permission to file like 777.

if it's not work here is solution:

1- in apache config file set user and group to root, however it's completely mad and it's not right way to fix this problem because of security issue

2- add your script in sudoer file in /etc/ and run that script in another script with sudo prefix. it's not a bad as number 1 but still you can have security problem. be carefull